# Troubles with Current Session Context Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm coding web library project and I have an issue with Hibernate Current Session Context. I receive

> error 500 message  No CurrentSessionContext configured!

when I try to access *books* page. When I try to access index page everything is OK

Index page

[image]

Internal error 500 NoCurrentSessionConfigured

[image]

It is my Hibernate Configuration file

```
package com.library.config;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.library")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class HibernateConfig {

    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.library.model");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

BookController.java

```
package com.library.controller;

import com.library.service.BookService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @GetMapping
    public String allBooks(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("books", bookService.findAll());
        return "books";
    }

}
```

BookServiceImpl.java

```
package com.library.service.impl;

import com.library.dao.BookDAO;
import com.library.model.Book;
import com.library.service.BookService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {

    @Autowired
    private BookDAO bookDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addBook(Book book) {
        bookDAO.addBook(book);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Book> findAll() {
        return bookDAO.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Book findBookById(Integer id) {
        return bookDAO.findBookById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Book findBookByTitle(String title) {
        return bookDAO.findBookByTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateBook(Book book) {
        bookDAO.updateBook(book);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteBook(Book book) {
        bookDAO.deleteBook(book);
    }
}
```

BookDAO.java

```
package com.library.dao.impl;

import com.library.dao.BookDAO;
import com.library.model.Book;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class BookDAOImpl implements BookDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void addBook(Book book) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(book);
    }

    @Override
    public List findAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Books").list();
    }

    @Override
    public Book findBookById(Integer id) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Book.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public Book findBookByTitle(String title) {
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from books where title=:title");
        query.setParameter("title", title);
        return (Book) query.uniqueResult();
    }

//    @Override
//    public List<Book> findBookByAuthor(Author author) {
//        return null;
//    }

    @Override
    public void updateBook(Book book) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(book);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteBook(Book book) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(book);
    }
}
```

application.properies

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Library
jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password = password
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
```

It is my project structure

[image: Project structure]

I have tried different things such as changing `getCurrentSession()` to `openSession()`
or adding

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext
</property>
```

or

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
thread
</property>
```

Also checked connection with database. Nothing helps. Could you please, suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because "sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()" and there's no session opened,I suggest you try to open a session from your sessionFactory object e.g
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); ,do the findAll with the session object and then close it,hope it works for you !